# IE11 table-cell height

Tags: html, css

I have a table-esque layout but can't seem to get all the "cells" to be the same height.

Here is what I have so far, does anyone see what I'm missing? Or should I just go with a block display wrapper with child inline wrappers?

```css
.input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    height: 18px;
}

.table-row{
  display: table-row;
  height: 18px;
}

input.form-control {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 12px;
    border-right-width: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: table-cell;
}


.input-group .input-group-addon {
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 0;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left-width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: table-cell;
}

.input-group .fdsa {
    background-color: #ec7404;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table-cell;
}

.fa-euro:before, .fa-eur:before {
    content: "€";
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="table-row">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="AmountInput" value="50">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-eur"></i>
        </span>

        <span class="fdsa" id="BtnFormSubmit">
            Submit
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `display: flex`

```css
.input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 18px;
}

.table-row{
  display: flex;
  height: 18px;
}

input.form-control {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 12px;
    border-right-width: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
}


.input-group .input-group-addon {
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 0;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left-width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

.input-group .fdsa {
    background-color: #ec7404;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;

}

.fa-euro:before, .fa-eur:before {
    content: "€";
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="table-row">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="AmountInput" value="50">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-eur"></i>
        </span>

        <span class="fdsa" id="BtnFormSubmit">
            Submit
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```